# What is eating my memory? (The SAW, JS mem usage edition)

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection

So, I heard you can supposedly do all fancy real-time games using JS these days. And I'm no beginner at it, so I though I should give it a try. Wrote some micro (incomplete) physics engine with some collision detection, all sweet. Somewhat laggy though, expected GC interrupts. So tried to minimize any allocation, till I was unable to see anything that should allocate memory in game loop. No allocations => no cleanup I though. But here is what I get:
[image]

Now, this is not neat at all. So I tried removing my stuff from game loop in various ways. Still SAW. So no I present you the complete code that generates this:

```
<html><body><script>
    function draw() { console.log(1); }
    ;(function () {
        function main(tFrame) { draw(); window.requestAnimationFrame( main ); }
        main();
    })();
</script></body></html>
```

Amazing? Well this uses requestAnimationFrame as it seems this is what should be used for smooth performance. At first I tried set interval like so:

```
<html><body><script>
    function draw() { console.log(1); }
    window.setInterval(draw, 0);
</script></body></html>
```

Exactly the same thing!

This seems completely unacceptable, but I have no ideas how to stop this SAW. I looked a lot about debugging memory and stuff, that was while I though that problem was in my drawing and updating functions. But these to snippets, have basically nothing, and yet they produce that memory patter. Maybe it is my browser? Or is it inescapable, and JS is unusable for anything real-time? I would like to believe that someone on the web knows something I don't as there are lot's of people promising wonders with JS.
What am I doing wrong in these snippets?

EDIT: by the way removing console log changes nothing, in case anyone thinks thats the problem.

Comment: Any browser plugins running in the background?

Comment: Also if someone can't reproduce this, would be interesting to hear OS and browser version. I'm on Linux testing with Chromium 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: @sixfingeredman nope, just a couple of open tabs on blank (well something was opened but I "backed"). Not that that should have any effect as chrome has process isolation, and I would hope it can detect if plug-in or page is using CPU, and especially mem.

Comment: I removed the console.log and made sure not to open the elements tab of the devtools, and the memory usage stayed constant: http://i.imgur.com/ntiqkOl.png. Chrome 41.0.2272.74 beta-m on Win7.

Comment: What OS and what version? I tried with fresh instance without log still same.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m, Windows 8.1. Do you see this mem usage on any other, unrelated tabs? Do you see this mem usage if you create a new page with only the code you posted here - perhaps you missed something when turning things off?

Answer (score 5):

Let's analyze that code a bit:

- You are creating 3 functions on startup
- You are creating 1 integer per draw call (60+ times per second)
- You are logging once per draw call (which is super slow by the way)

Here is the performance of creating integers vs doing nothing vs logging in JavaScript:

[image: Creating Integers versus logging them]

http://jsperf.com/creating-integers

You are however right. After visiting an `about:blank` page and tweaking your code a bit I got some interesting data.

Code:

```
function draw() { 1; }

function main(tFrame) { 
    draw(); 
    window.requestAnimationFrame( main ); 
}

main();
```

Data:

[image: GC JS Saw]

This graph is fluctuating between 4.6MB and 5.2MB. Not such a big deal actually. Freeing half a megabyte of memory is really fast. Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid this. I tried the following:

```
var j = 1;

function draw() { j; }
```

And while there was less garbage to collect; GC still ran. On the plus side in both this example and the previous our code runs at 60fps at all times:

[image: 60fps... no logging]

Moral of the story: logging is expensive. It is always expensive; javascript or not.

Comment: Logging actually was there to make sure code was looping, and I did not remove when posting quest. My main problem is that, this, as you show also happens when noting remains, it happens for me even when function body is empty. As for it is not a problem, well I'd say it is. In my real code with simulation, it is visible that some frames take longer. Also interesting thing is empty code saws teeth take about 30 seconds, but with simulation teeth are considerably shorter maybe even sub second.

Comment: @morphles I don't know exactly what you are doing during your loop. JS is single threaded and needs more attention to get good performance. General tips: 1) you should devise a strategy for not updating during the render loop if at all possible. I often handle events outside of the loop and have them tweak data. In that way the render loop remains a read only code path. 2) simplify your scene in some way (culling/level of detail/rtrees) this lets you process just certain parts of the screen. 3) If you absolutely need more horse power consider web workers. 4) typed arrays. Are you using webgl?

Comment: yeah maybe I'll try moving updates into set timeout and leave drawing to animframe. 2, for now schiene is very simple, even couple of balls bouncing of lines look same as 300 balls (which is weird, and this makes me suspect GC more than anything else). For now I doubt that typed arrays would give me much (again 300 vs 3 balls, lag seems same). I'm not using webgl, and don't really want to use it.

Comment: @morphles are using canvas then? Or svg?

Comment: canvas.But the IMO such GC churn is unacceptable.Especially on empty loop.At first I though it was my code (and well there was quite some allocations in it), so I removed any object or string creation in loop methods.Basically only number assignments to global object properties remain.And some string variables are obviously being assigned to canvas style properties. But as I understand none of that should cause any allocations. But surprisingly number of balls simulated affects frequency of saw teeth very visibly. Of course empty loop GC'ing is still "best"... Maybe JS ain't up to it:)

Comment: @morphles I don't think that's the case. I have seen pretty intensive applications work just fine in JS land. There are a few box2d implementations that seem to work.  There are also other physics and rendering engines in js already as well. Webgl is significantly more performant than canvas by the way. While the GC churn does cause slow downs. Its generally OK. You'd have the same problem is Java and that works alright.

Comment: I tried box2d, was seriously not satisfied with it. It might be OK for physics style stacking games, but it does not seem suitable to some real time shooter game. Part of this is it's simulation is overly more advanced than needed, making it hard to optimize. I instead used hand written very simple verlet based integration for simulation, and it seemed to work much better. Though my collision handling is considerably more limited at least for now. But again that makes things much simpler. I'm simply not really a fan of running gl in browser :)